# unable to pass parameter to indexed or parametrized query in spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to pass a parameter to my query, but it is passing? instead of passing value to it.

Tried to pass as indexed as well as parameter but in both cases I can see `?` only.

Here is my interface:

```
package com.Efive.Dao;



import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.Efive.Model.FileModel;

public interface FillDataDao extends CrudRepository<FileModel, Integer>{
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(file_model.formid), 0) + 1 FROM file_model"
            ,nativeQuery = true)
    int getfilemodelmaxid();
    
    @Query(value = "select*from file_model LIMIT 10;"
            ,nativeQuery = true)
    List<FileModel> getfilemodelallrecord();

    @Query(value = "SELECT n FROM File_model n WHERE n.LANGUAGE = ?1",nativeQuery = true)
    List<FileModel> getfilemodelallrecordBySearch(String searchTerm);

}
```

`getfilemodelmaxid()` and `List<FileModel> getfilemodelallrecord()` works fine as we are not passing any parameter to it but facing problem in `List<FileModel> getfilemodelallrecordBySearch(String searchTerm)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

There's a minor error in query.
Just replace `SELECT n` by `SELECT *`

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM File_model n WHERE n.LANGUAGE = ?1",nativeQuery = true)
    List<FileModel> getfilemodelallrecordBySearch(String searchTerm);

Hope this works !!
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please mention the issue with  getfilemodelallrecordBySearch(String searchTerm).

you can always use JPA methods for simple queries like this. JPA will automatically convert it to the queries.

```
List<FileModel> findAllByLanguage(String searchTerm);
```

please read how to use JPA method here. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Comment: But what if I want to use LIKE in query or search for term in multiple field.

Comment: List<FileModel> findAllByLanguageLike(String searchTerm);
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries